# Generative modelling: what if the generating models have very different "quality of fit"

Tags: classification, generative-models

Say I want to classify my data into two categories. I am pretty sure that my data has been generated by two mixtures of Gaussians -- on has a bimodal and one a trimodal form.

I then train the generating models $p(x|c_1)$ and $p(x|c_2)$ and combine them via Bayes' theorem into a classifier of the form $p(c_i|x)$.

Since both models are obtained by an optimization process, I don't have any guarantee that they fit their class equally well. Actually, it might be that one of the models assigns too much probability mass to points from the other class *solely* due to the fact that I let the optimization process run too long, chose the wrong model or whatever.

As you can see, I just chose the mixture of Gaussians example only for the sake of the optimization. It might as well be hidden Markov models or even wrong modeling assumptions.

Does this have a name? Are there principled ways to overcome this?